# how can express session store things like OAuth instance?

Tags: node.js, express

how can I do this in express?

```
req.session.oa = new OAuth(....);

// and in another request
req.session.oa.getOAuthToken(...);
```

the session is store in redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` in the session and have the OAuth object be in `app.settings`.

So you would have

```
app.configure('development', function() {
  // ...
  app.set('OACLIENT', new OAuth(...));
  // ...
});
```

And then in the routes

```
var params = {
   token: req.session.oa.access_token,
   token_secret: req.session.oa.access_token_secret
};
req.app.settings.OACLIENT.function(params /* Or whatever */)
```